# how to use nav2d with my own lidar and slam algorithm?

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm trying to do  this job,here is the scene:
I want to take my lidar move around a house ,and i hope nav2d could give me a path about how to move to the most proper frontiers,my slam algorithm is cartographer not karto.
now i've already run the tutorial3.launch,but i still don't know how to achieve it with my own lidar and slam algorithm...for example i don't know how to modify tutorial3.launch to make it work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258697/how-to-use-nav2d-with-my-own-lidar-and-slam-algorithm?/) by [xbc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29946/xbc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You actually just have to replace the Karto-Mapper with your own mapping algorithm. Make sure that your mapper provides the map via a service of type [GetMap](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetMap.html), so that the navigator can use it to plan exploration on it.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xbc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29946/xbc/) on 2017-04-08**:
I did what you told me to do ,but something unexpectedly happened..I change my tutorial3.launch' s mapper part :<node name="cartographer_node" pkg="cartographer_ros" type="cartographer_node",But when I type rosservice call /StartExploration,nothing happened..I'm preety confused.Do you know why ?